# Confused about classes in Learn Python the Hard Way ex43?

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm confused on how the Map and Engine classes together work together to run this Adventureland type game (full code here: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html). I think I understand what is happening in the Map class, but I'm really confused about what is happening in Engine() and why the scene_map variable is needed.

```
class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
        'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
        'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
        'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
        'death': Death()
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()

        while True:
            print "\n--------"
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The `Engine` class is just a mechanism for running the game with a given initial scene (map). So a game is initiated by creating an instance of the `Engine` class with a starting map `a_game = Engine(a_map))`, and then played out by executing the `play` method (`a_game.play()`. Stated another way, `Engine` encapsulates the execution of a game.

Comment: @mbratch: Well, the map isn't the initial scene, it's the collection of _all_ of the scenes, and the way they're connected up. But otherwise, good description.

Comment: @abarnert, indeed, but the instance of the `Map` is created with an initial scene, e.g., 'central_corridor'. That's what I was referring to.

Comment: It should probably be noted this is like "toy code".  Though it illustrates concepts you could use to build a real world game, the code is more about illustrating Python objects and is not necessarily the best or most intuitive design.  That said, I learned a lot from reverse engineering this code myself.a  The map() class is inappropriately named.  It drives the flow of the game with a list of "locations" a user can end up in, and methods that move the user around in the flow of the game.  Engine and map work together to build the main crux of the flow through the simple story.  But ...

Comment: The game does not have to be designed this way.  In good OO design, you would think through what you might be able to re-use in what way in the future and carve up your code accordingly.  In theory, different map()s could be designed and hooked to the same engine, but the engine does so little, and the map is designed more around encapsellation then reuse.  This is more of a demo of object syntax then OO design but for students, it is a useful bit of code to pick apart and learn from.

Answer (score 3):

The `Engine` instance's `scene_map` is an instance of the `Map` class, just as the global `a_map` is. In fact, `a_game.scene_map` is the *same* instance as `a_map`.

So, whatever you could do with `a_map` at the top level, the `Engine.play` code can do with `self.scene_map`. It may be worth typing everything into the interactive interpreter up to the `a_map` definition and playing around with a_map to make sure you know what exactly it can do for you.

So, why does `Engine` need `self.scene_map`? Why can't it just use the global `a_map`?

Well, it *could*. The problem is that if you did that, you wouldn't be able to create two `Engine` instances without them fighting over the same `a_map`. (This is the same reason you don't want to use global variables in functions. Objects don't add a new problem—in fact, a big part of what objects are about is *solving* the global-variables problem.)