# Trying to understand flow and logic of a simple python game that uses objects and classes

Tags: python, oop

I'm working through Learn Python the Hard Way tutorial. I've gone back a few exercises to try to really get my head around Zed's (Authors) OOP example game (exercise 43).

Cautiously, I think I get it - what classes and objects are. I do in theory at least understand the difference between a Fish and a salmon, a car and a Honda etc etc.

I understand that we use classes and objects (as opposed to just writing functions on demand) in order to reuse code (right?).

My chain of thought is delicate right now but I cannot rest, sleep or feel content till I get this to really click.

The game has a number of scenes (scene is a class in the game). E.g. Central Corridor, The Bridge, Escape Pod.

In addition to the scenes the game uses an Engine and a Map (objects). I do not understand fully how these components make the game run.

At the very end of the script, to start the game is the code block:

```
a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

Specific questions:

1. How does the game move from scene to scene?
2. How do the engine and map classes work in the game? I.e. What does the engine and map do? I cannot follow the logic fully. Ideally this could be explained with an example, such as the steps in the code from moving from TheBridge to EscapePod (the last two scenes in the game flow)
3. Is my statement correct: "I understand that we use classes and objects (as opposed to just writing functions on demand) in order to reuse code."

Here is the game:

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint

class Scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print "This scene is not yet configured. Subclass it and implement enter()."

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        print "Engine __init__ has scene_map", scene_map
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        print "Play's first scene", current_scene

        while True:
            print "\n--------"
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            print "next scene", next_scene_name
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
            print "map returns new scene", current_scene

class Death(Scene):

    quips = [
        "You died. You kinda suck at this.",
        "Your mom would be proud... if she were smarter",
        "Such a luser",
        "I have a small puppy that's better at this."
        ]

    def enter(self):
        print Death.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]
        exit(1)

class CentralCorridor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "The Gothons of Planet Percal #25 have invaded your ship and destroyed"
        print "your entire crew.  You are the last surviving member and your last"
        print "mission is to get the neutron destruct bomb from the Weapons Armory,"
        print "put it in the bridge, and blow the ship up after getting into an "
        print "escape pod."
        print "\n"
        print "You're running down the central corridor to the Weapons Armory when"
        print "a Gothon jumps out, red scaly skin, dark grimy teeth, and evil clown costume"
        print "flowing around his hate filled body.  He's blocking the door to the"
        print "Armory and about to pull a weapon to blast you."

        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "shoot!":
            print "Quick on the draw you yank out your blaster and fire it at the Gothon."
            print "His clown costume is flowing and moving around his body, which throws"
            print "off your aim.  Your laser hits his costume but misses him entirely.  This"
            print "completely ruins his brand new costume his mother bought him, which"
            print "makes him fly into an insane rage and blast you repeatedly in the face until"
            print "you are dead.  Then he eats you."
            return 'death'

        elif action == "dodge!":
            print "Like a world class boxer you dodge, weave, slip and slide right"
            print "as the Gothon's blaster cranks a laser past your head."
            print "In the middle of your artful dodge your foot slips and you"
            print "bang your head on the metal wall and pass out."
            print "You wake up shortly after only to die as the Gothon stomps on"
            print "your head and eats you."
            return 'death'

        elif action == "tell a joke":
            print "Lucky for you they made you learn Gothon insults in the academy."
            print "You tell the one Gothon joke you know:"
            print "Lbhe zbgure vf fb sng, jura fur fvgf nebhaq gur ubhfr, fur fvgf nebhaq gur ubhfr."
            print "The Gothon stops, tries not to laugh, then busts out laughing and can't move."
            print "While he's laughing you run up and shoot him square in the head"
            print "putting him down, then jump through the Weapon Armory door."
            return 'laser_weapon_armory'

        else:
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE!"
            return 'central_corridor'

class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "You do a dive roll into the Weapon Armory, crouch and scan the room"
        print "for more Gothons that might be hiding.  It's dead quiet, too quiet."
        print "You stand up and run to the far side of the room and find the"
        print "neutron bomb in its container.  There's a keypad lock on the box"
        print "and you need the code to get the bomb out.  If you get the code"
        print "wrong 10 times then the lock closes forever and you can't"
        print "get the bomb.  The code is 3 digits."
        code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
        guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")
        guesses = 0

        while guess != code and guesses < 10:
            print "BZZZZEDDD!"
            guesses += 1
            guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")

        if guess == code:
            print "The container clicks open and the seal breaks, letting gas out."
            print "You grab the neutron bomb and run as fast as you can to the"
            print "bridge where you must place it in the right spot."
            return 'the_bridge'
        else:
            print "The lock buzzes one last time and then you hear a sickening"
            print "melting sound as the mechanism is fused together."
            print "You decide to sit there, and finally the Gothons blow up the"
            print "ship from their ship and you die."
            return 'death'

class TheBridge(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "You burst onto the Bridge with the netron destruct bomb"
        print "under your arm and surprise 5 Gothons who are trying to"
        print "take control of the ship.  Each of them has an even uglier"
        print "clown costume than the last.  They haven't pulled their"
        print "weapons out yet, as they see the active bomb under your"
        print "arm and don't want to set it off."

        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "throw the bomb":
            print "In a panic you throw the bomb at the group of Gothons"
            print "and make a leap for the door.  Right as you drop it a"
            print "Gothon shoots you right in the back killing you."
            print "As you die you see another Gothon frantically try to disarm"
            print "the bomb. You die knowing they will probably blow up when"
            print "it goes off."
            return 'death'

        elif action == "slowly place the bomb":
            print "You point your blaster at the bomb under your arm"
            print "and the Gothons put their hands up and start to sweat."
            print "You inch backward to the door, open it, and then carefully"
            print "place the bomb on the floor, pointing your blaster at it."
            print "You then jump back through the door, punch the close button"
            print "and blast the lock so the Gothons can't get out."
            print "Now that the bomb is placed you run to the escape pod to"
            print "get off this tin can."
            return 'escape_pod'
        else:
            print "DOES NOT COMPUTE!"
            return "the_bridge"

class EscapePod(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "You rush through the ship desperately trying to make it to"
        print "the escape pod before the whole ship explodes.  It seems like"
        print "hardly any Gothons are on the ship, so your run is clear of"
        print "interference.  You get to the chamber with the escape pods, and"
        print "now need to pick one to take.  Some of them could be damaged"
        print "but you don't have time to look.  There's 5 pods, which one"
        print "do you take?"

        good_pod = randint(1,5)
        guess = raw_input("[pod #]> ")


        if int(guess) != good_pod:
            print "You jump into pod %s and hit the eject button." % guess
            print "The pod escapes out into the void of space, then"
            print "implodes as the hull ruptures, crushing your body"
            print "into jam jelly."
            return 'death'
        else:
            print "You jump into pod %s and hit the eject button." % guess
            print "The pod easily slides out into space heading to"
            print "the planet below.  As it flies to the planet, you look"
            print "back and see your ship implode then explode like a"
            print "bright star, taking out the Gothon ship at the same"
            print "time.  You won!"

            return 'finished'

class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
        'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
        'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
        'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
        'death': Death()
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene
        print "start_scene in __init__", self.start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        print "start_scene in next_scene"
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        print "next_scene returns", val
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. How does the game move from scene to scene?**

**2. How do the engine and map classes work in the game? I.e. What does the engine and map do?**

Probably best to answer these two questions together.

The `Engine` sets up the flow of the game, via the `play()` method. Each iteration of the `while` loop in that method, you might consider to be a single "turn" or "round" in game terms. In each distinct term/round, the following things happen in the following order:

- A faux-horizontal rule is printed;
- The *name* of the next scene is determined *by the current scene's `enter()` method*;
- A descriptive line is printed;
- The *name* of the next scene is given to `scene_map` to return the corresponding *class*;
- A descriptive line is printed.

The first, third, and fifth lines of the `while` loop are there only for your convenience in seeing what's going on as you play through the game. The real meat is in the second and fourth lines.

How does the game move from scene to scene? Well, the `Engine` class only knows that the `Scene` is going to give it a name, and it's going to look at its `scene_map` to see which *class* goes with that name. The `scene_map` is basically a dictionary with added functionality to yell HEY GUESS WHAT I'M DOING NOW while it gives you the *class* that you identified by *name*. The `Engine` doesn't need to know what happens during a `Scene`, or how the user chooses the next `Scene`; all it does is keep you moving along those repeating five steps that make up each round.

How we move from one scene to the next depends on the scene we're currently in. When you write a class that inherits from `Scene`, you have to define an `enter()` method, and the only thing you really need to do to make sure you've written a functional scene is to make sure your `enter()` method is going to at some point return (to the `Engine`) the name of the next scene. Read some of the scenes, you'll notice they return different *scene names* when the user provides different input.

Of course, if your functional scene doesn't appear in the `scene_map`, and there are no other scenes that can potentially return its name, thus directing the `Engine` to call its `enter()` method, your functional scene is impossible to access.

I typed this up pretty quickly as it's the end of the day, but hopefully I said some things in a way that you found helpful... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks AirThomas that spells it out for me

Answer (score 5):

1. the key part of the game is this code:

   ```
   while True: 
       next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()  # <-- returns after interaction with user
       current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
   ```

   Each scene's `enter` method returns the name of the next scene to go to (depending on the player's actions)... this may be the same scene again. Then the `next_scene` method of the `Map` class returns the scene instance matching that name and we assign that to the `current_scene` variable... then it loops around and 'enters' the new current scene. This will go on endlessly, or until you reach the `Death` scene which exits the program.
2. the `Engine` class is basically explained above. IMHO it's not necessary for this to be a class, it would be just as effective (and simpler, therefore better) to have just a bare `play` function such as:

   ```
   def play(scene_map):
       current_scene = scene_map.opening_scene()
       print "Play's first scene", current_scene

       while True:
           print "\n--------"
           next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
           print "next scene", next_scene_name
           current_scene = scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
           print "map returns new scene", current_scene
   ```

   and to start the game running by:

   ```
   a_map = Map('central_corridor')
   play(a_map)
   ```

   The `Map` class matches scene-object instances to scene names like `'central_corridor'`... the core of the class is the dictionary which contains the actual mapping. You can see that the `next_scene` method of the class just does a `get` on the dict key. In fact you could simplify the code by eliminating the `Map` class and just have a bare dict, moving the trivial start-scene logic into the `Engine` class (or `play` method as I suggested above).

   However in the case of the `Map` class I would suggest it serves another useful purpose by defining an *[API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface#API_in_object-oriented_languages)*... in other words a set of methods relevant for working with a game map. This means that later on in the development of your game if you realise you need a more complicated implementation of Map logic than just a dict, as long as you keep the API the same (i.e. the name and arguments of the methods) you don't have to change the rest of your code.
3. A class defines a set of behaviours and presents an interface to them. An object is an instance of a class, it is a collection of run-time state (i.e. the specific values of the attributes of the class).

   It's not really about code reuse. Code reuse implies having sub-classes which inherit behaviour from the parent (instead of having to copy and paste that behaviour) but you can get value from using classes without any sub-classing going on. A class is like a template for creating objects which have a common behaviour.

   In the game code as it stands currently some of the use of classes is rather pointless.  For example the `Engine` class... you initialise it with a `Map` instance and call its `play` method but since you'll only ever have a single instance of an `Engine` there's no point encapsulating that state (the `self.scene_map` attribute) in a class - you could just pass that state into the `play` method at the point you call it.

   Similarly the `Scene` class and sub-classes thereof. Yes, the `Scene` class defines an interface ("scenes will have an `enter` method") but since each scene does not contain any unique state (i.e. attributes on `self`) there's no need to have an instantiated object, you could achieve the same thing more simply with just bare functions.

   Hopefully the intent is to develop these classes into more useful structures, which justify the use of classes, in future stages of the tutorial.

You may like to explore further the meaning of these terms:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_science)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)

And similar question on SO:
[Confused about classes in Learn Python the Hard Way ex43?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199031/confused-about-classes-in-learn-python-the-hard-way-ex43?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's really helpful and I hope others on this tutorial (Since posting I've noticed a few other folk on SO asking about this tutorials exercise 43) also find it helpful.