# a dict being defined in a python class but outside any method

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I was going through the code given here : [Confused about classes in Learn Python the Hard Way ex43?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199031/confused-about-classes-in-learn-python-the-hard-way-ex43?rq=1)

when I found out that a dict is defined in the class Map(object) but not in any method. Here is what I mean :

```
class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
        'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
        'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
        'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
        'death': Death()
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)
```

Later the dict is used in next_scene method. I did not know that anything can be defined in a class outside a method except docstring. Can you please explain how this dict is being used?

Comment: It's like a `static` member variable in C++ or Java. No matter how many instances of the class you create, all of them will share the same variable (so there's no need to recreate it for every instance).

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell, there exists a single instance of this dictionary. It is called `Map.scenes` and is shared by all instances of the class.

> did not know that anything can be defined in a class outside a method except docstring.

In actual fact, you can put pretty much any executable statement inside `class`:

```
class HHGTTG(object):
  print 42
```

Even `def` is an executable statement in Python.

Comment: can i replace this dict with a variable???? or is it a good practice do declare such a global variable in a class inside ____init____ method???

Comment: @kartikey_kant: This dict **is** a variable. Its name is `scenes`, and you should refer to it with `Map.scenes` instead of `self.scenes`.

Comment: i'm saying can i put something like  **anything = x + y + z** outside any method so that it can be referred to as **class.anything**